# Polymer change data array on the fly

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am trying to change the source array of a paper-tabs menu trough the selection of another one. `{{lastResponse.0.lessons}}` works perfectly. But when I try to generate this I just get an error.

API Response:

```
[
{
    "date": "2016-02-23",
    "lessons": [
        "06a",
        "08e",
        "09b",
        "10b",
        "10c",
        "10d",
        "10e",
        "11",
        "12"
    ]
},
{
    "date": "2016-02-24",
    "lessons": [
        "05a",
        "05b",
        "05c",
        "05d",
        "06a",
        "08b",
        "08c",
        "08d",
        "08e",
        "09b",
        "09c",
        "10b",
        "10c",
        "10d",
        "10e",
        "11",
        "12"
    ]
},
...
]
```

Element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="vplan-gykl-test">
<template>
    <iron-ajax
            auto
            id="getMenu"
            url="../../../private/api/getMenu.php"
            params='{"school":"gykl"}'
            handle-as="json"
            last-response="{{lastResponse}}">
    </iron-ajax>

    <paper-tabs selected="{{selectedDate}}" id="date" scrollable>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{lastResponse}}">
            <paper-tab>{{item.date}}</paper-tab>
        </template>
    </paper-tabs>


    <paper-tabs selected="{{selectedClass}}" id="class" scrollable>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{lastResponse.[[selectedDate]].lessons}}">
            <paper-tab>{{item}}</paper-tab>
        </template>
    </paper-tabs>

</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'vplan-gykl-test',

        properties: {
            selectedDate: {
                type: Number,
                value: 0
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I tried to use a computed string (same error):

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'vplan-gykl-test',

        properties: {
            selectedDate: {
                type: Number,
                value: 0
            },
            targetArray: {
                computed: 'computeTargetArray(selectedDate)'
            }
        },
        computeTargetArray: function(index) {
            return('{{lastResponse.' + index + '.lessons}}');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Error:

```
[dom-repeat::dom-repeat]: expected array for `items`, found {{lastResponse.0.lessons}}
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You approach with computing the target array is the way to go. However, instead of returning a String, you should directly return the array. Something along these lines:

```
    computeTargetArray: function(index) {
        return this.lastResponse[index].lessons;
    }
```

Make sure that `lastResponse` is defined as a property on your element and that you also define a type for `targetArray`.

```
    properties: {
        selectedDate: {
            type: Number,
            value: 0
        },
        targetArray: {
            type: Array,
            computed: 'computeTargetArray(selectedDate, lastResponse)'
        },
        lastResponse: {
            type: Array
        },

    },
```

If you also add `lastResponse` as a parameter to the computed function, the function will only be called, when it is defined.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Seems logical. When I copy your code I get following error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` I'm new to Polymer Javascript so I didn't find an easy solution.

Comment: I have expanded my answer a bit. I hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah forgot to define it in the properties. Thanks a lot!